# ASP.NET 4 Webforms Routing

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, routes, webforms

I'm creating a CMS, and want all request sent to Default.aspx except for the administrator route. Here is what I have:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("favicon.ico");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Administrator",
            "Administrator",
            "~/Admin/Default.aspx");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("CMS",
            "{PageURL}",
            "~/Default.aspx");
    }
```

This is working for a request such as:

mywebsite.com
mywebsite.com/test
mywebsite.com/anothertest

However, I get a resource cannot be found for:

mywebsite.com/another/test

How can I alter my routing so that it catches multiple levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try making your `{PageURL}` into `{*PageURL}` (or I even think `{*}` will work, but am not sure) using route wildcards.

Or, you could do something like `PageURL/{*TheRest}`

Just remember that wildcards are very powerful and should be put at the end of your routes since routes are figured out in order.

Comment: Thanks, adding RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("CMS",
                "{*PageURL}",
                "~/Default.aspx"); as the bottom route does the trick